# WSO2 IS 5.7 is failing on production deployment regarding DefaultRealm

Tags: java, wso2, openldap, wso2-identity-server

My code:
https://github.com/MrClemRkz/Identity.git

Run the code by running start.sh bash file. You may reset using reset.sh bash file. I'm using these bash files for easy configuration for the use of other application. Therefore those are necessary.

I have hosted on AWS and I got only the IP Address pointing the server.

This works well on localhost. Yet on deployment following error occurs when starting the server.

Error StackTrace:

```html
[2018-11-04 18:33:17,527] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:395)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:264)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:349)
 ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user has not been created. Error occurs while creating Admin user in primary user store.
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:5838)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:244)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:122)
 ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Can not access the directory context oruser already exists in the system
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.getSearchBaseDirectoryContext(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:364)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddUser(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:260)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:5832)
 ... 29 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'ou=Users,dc=copper,dc=opensource,dc=lk'
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3179)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3100)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2891)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_lookup(LdapCtx.java:1033)
 at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentContext.p_lookup(ComponentContext.java:542)
 at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.lookup(PartialCompositeContext.java:177)
 at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.lookup(PartialCompositeContext.java:166)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.getSearchBaseDirectoryContext(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:357)
 ... 31 more
[2018-11-04 18:33:17,530] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:274)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:316)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:264)
 ... 19 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:395)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
 ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:349)
 ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user has not been created. Error occurs while creating Admin user in primary user store.
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:5838)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:244)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:122)
 ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Can not access the directory context oruser already exists in the system
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.getSearchBaseDirectoryContext(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:364)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddUser(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:260)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:5832)
 ... 29 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'ou=Users,dc=copper,dc=opensource,dc=lk'
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3179)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3100)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2891)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_lookup(LdapCtx.java:1033)
 at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentContext.p_lookup(ComponentContext.java:542)
 at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.lookup(PartialCompositeContext.java:177)
 at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.lookup(PartialCompositeContext.java:166)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
 at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.getSearchBaseDirectoryContext(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:357)
 ... 31 more
[2018-11-04 18:33:25,183]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[2018-11-04 18:33:25,335]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.x509Certificate.internal.X509CertificateServiceComponent} -  X509 Certificate Servlet activated successfully..
```

Comment: I suspect it may be due to connection issue with LDAP, You follow this blog to check whether there are any connections issues. Use debug enabled
https://medium.com/@senthalan/check-connection-with-the-ldap-server-60125b96615f